# Compile time generation/check of urls in razor pages

Tags: routes, razor-pages, .net-6.0

This is 2022 and running on 20 years of development of the .net stack (ie .net 6.0).

I have to assume it is possible to make an app that uses razor page that doesn't depend on me writing magically correct strings and magic anonymous classes...

It took me 2 hours to figure out why `Url.Page("MyPage", new {id = o.UniqueId})` was returning `null`.

1. There is no compile time check for `MyPage`
2. There is no compile time check for `id`
3. There is no compile time check for the type of `id`
4. There is no compile time check for missing or extra parameters
5. There is no compile time check for this actually giving me a reasonable url, because as it turns out, this needed a `new {id = o.UniqueId, area="anothermagicstring"}`

But hours of searching on google has given me no clue how to solve these 5 issues.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How to get compile time checks of all urls generation in razor pages.